# ServiceStack adding roles and permissions with custom AuthUserSession

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to add roles and permissions when a new user is registered. I'm running into the problem that adding to the session roles and permissions does not get persisted to the database.

I've written a Custom **AuthUserSession** and overridden **OnAuthenticated**.

The code below uses the **AssignRolesService**, and that seems like it would be exactly what I need except for one problem. When the authentication is handled by Facebook auth provider **session.UserAuthName** is null so I can't call the service.

To clarify, all code snippets below are contained within:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, 
            IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
```

The suggested way of doing this (from what I found on SO/Google):

```
using (var assignRoles = authService.ResolveService<AssignRolesService>())
{
    assignRoles.Post(new AssignRoles {
        UserName = session.UserAuthName,
        Roles = { RoleNames.Admin }
    });
}
```

Also tried this but it did not work:

```
session.Roles.Add("user");
session.Permissions.Add("setup");
authService.SaveSession(session);
```

The only thing that I found that seems to work, but seems like a hack is:

```
UserAuth ua = db.GetById<UserAuth>(session.UserAuthId);
ua.UserName = user.Email;
ua.Roles.Add("user");
ua.Permissions.Add("setup");
db.Save(ua);
```

Comment: did you find a solution just by using the session user?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I just figured it out!

if just by a a coincidence you're using LoadUserInfo that have a try / catch when you are trying to assign the values, hiding a null reference exception and doing the redirect without doing a re-throw

that got fixed just by creating a new List like this:

```
 userSession.Roles = new List<string> {"your-role-here"};
```

Comment: Tried that in the OnAuthenticated override... no dice :/

Comment: this is an old post, that's servicestack 3.x if I can remember